# Sinhala text not showing correctly in text-box/ richtextbox?

Tags: c#, unicode, notepad, unicode-string

I am making a c# windows application in Visual Studio 2012 which is working with unicode. But the unicode texts displays in textboxes / richtextboxes have bined together and gives an uneven look.(language: Sinhala)

But when I copy and paste the same text from the textbox/ richtextbox to windows notepad it looks perfectely correct. So I feel like the the text in textbox/ richtextbox is correct in unicode, the thing is it cannot show the text correctly.

How to correct this ? Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: Please show code you use and more importantly what font you set to render (both in notepad and in your program). Also does it show the same in plain `TextBox` vs rich text box?

Comment: It shows same in testbox as the richtextbox. Font I use now is "Arial Unicode MS" for both. It shows correctly in notepad as above and more spaces between letters in richtextbox

Comment: Interesting... No idea why... Can you please confirm that Notepad uses that font too on your machine (Format->Font)?

Comment: Yes. And notepad is showing it correctly in other Unicode fonts too.

Answer (score 0):

Use this font **Noto Sans Sinhala**
download link
https://www.google.com/get/noto/#sans-sinh